# Does Gini index considers only a binary split for each attribute or can it have multi way spliting?

Tags: data-mining

Does Gini-index based classification split values for any attribute always as a binary split or can it split into more than $2$ branches (multi-way split)?

For more clarification, if a split on $A$ partitions $D$ into $D_1$ and $D_2$ , the Gini-index of $D$ given that partitioning is,

[image]

This is actually a binary split. Can there be also $D_4, D_5$ etc... too if it is not a binary split so that the formula will be,

[image]

Comment: i've just read all of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient and i can't find your function anywhere. do you have any references?

Comment: are u talking about my first equation or the 2nd one above?

Comment: both; is the 2nd equation inadmissible or something? it won't be a binary split:-)

Comment: First one is there in a book I read. I am asking whether the 2nd one is correct

Comment: if you have 3 partitions i would guess it follows

Comment: I want a confident answer. :-) bt thanks

Comment: I asked myself the same question and thus stumbled upon this question here. Do not let yourself get confused, @JonMarkPerry Gini index is not the same as Gini coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Gini-index can be used for multi-way splitting, like entropy. 
And the second formula you mentioned is correct if the feature has 3 distinct value, i.e. It can be generalized for more than this if the number of distinct values is more.